# WordPress plug-in that assigns a unique reference id and attach it to every post created?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working for a realty brokerage firm who have a requirement of generating a unique reference ID and attaches it to every property/post listed by individual agents. Such that when a customer likes a property they can only refer to it by the unique reference ID rather than the entire property name which could possibly lead to confusion. Is there an existing plug-in that does the same or any other beginner friendly way to do this on WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress posts come with a unique ID by default (the Post ID). This is a simple numerical value greater than 0. Why not create a fixed property ID such as PROP1234 and then append the post ID to create your unique reference?

So for a post with ID 398 you'd create a unique property ID of PROP1234398

This simply can be outputted in your template file as so:

```
<?php echo 'PROP1234' . get_the_ID(); ?>
```

If you wish to amend the permalink (URL of the post in the address bar) then you'll need to change the permalink structure like so (add to functions.php):

```
add_action('init', 'property_rewrite');

function property_rewrite() {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $queryarg = 'post_type=property&p=';
  $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%cpt_id%', '([^/]+)', $queryarg);
  $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('property', '/property/%postname%/PROP1234%cpt_id%', true, 1);
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'property_permalink', 1, 3);

function property_permalink($post_link, $id = 0, $leavename) {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $post = &get_post($id);
  if ( is_wp_error( $post ) )
    return $post;
  $newlink = $wp_rewrite->get_extra_permastruct('property');
  $newlink = str_replace("%cpt_id%", $post->ID, $newlink);
  $newlink = str_replace("%postname%", $post->post_name, $newlink);
  $newlink = home_url(user_trailingslashit($newlink));
  return $newlink;
}
```

This assumes you have created your property listings as a custom post type of 'property';

Comment: Hey! But then this reference ID will be only visible on the address bar, right? Not the post. Can this ID be appended to every post created automatically?

Comment: I've added additional code to my answer above to show how you can change this in the address bar. To output as text on a post, use the first snippet of code in a template file. Also in answer to your last question, yes, by using the permalink rewrite function, the url of the post will be generated automatically including the unique ID at the end of the url.

Comment: I believe the answer above is a solution to your problem. Please upvote it if I have answered the question satisfactorily.

Comment: Hi, Adam I did try to up vote your suggestion long back, but I need to have 15 rep points before I can up vote anybody. I'm sorry for it.